# What should I do if my boss is not paying me salary and asking me to work unreasonable hours?

Tags: management, salary, working-conditions

I am working as a software developer for very low pay. My boss is asking me to work more than 14 hours a day and he does not allow me to have Sundays off. He has asked me to do complete many jobs at the same time. He not only makes me do office work but also his personal projects and he tells me that he will pay for everything extra but he never does. Last Sunday I asked my boss if I could have leave for 2 days but he says very seriously, "You should not go to any where and your life is only the computer and nothing more." I do agree with what he says, but still he tries to control everything such as that I should not sleep till work is completed even if that work could not be completed in one day.

Even I am trying to work without sleep for continuously 2 days, he is not paying me for anything like overtime or out of hours. There are more issues as well which he gets involved in like if I talk with other employee, he gets angry at me and says "why are you talking to him" as well as similar situations. Now I am thinking I have to quit that job, even I do not have any other job to go to but he is harassing and torturing me a lot.

I am in dilemma, what should I do? Should I quit that job calmly saying that I can not work anymore with this company or should I kept all aside what he does to me and continue working like this. My life has been hell for the past 2 years and its almost 1 year since I have been to my home.

I really I don't know what to do and I don't know what decision will make my future life a any better then how it currently is.

Comment: if your boss has a boss go to that guy and complain (bring proof)

Comment: You may want to add what cultural context this is.

Comment: I made some edits to this but it is still very localized.

Comment: Your boss represents everything wrong with humanity.  He is bullying you and is treating you like a slave.  This is not normal.  This is not right.  This is the same kind of boss that forced the Bangladesh textile workers to enter the factory to work when it was obvious the building was collapsing.  Don't let that be your fate.

Comment: Yes, he is treating me like a slave. I cried lot of days that he blames me for his wrong things done with our superior and he tells that he is the one who does not work and he tells me that you are the person who can't work, but still we are feeding you freely. I am very shamed to tell my mother about what he does to me like even If I eat something, he tells that "you are eating total huh?" like these things many many. If I keep on writing about him what he has done to me, it will come to 1000 pages book.  I am in big dilemma whether to quit that job and look for another?

Comment: @Ganesh how is this a dilemma? From what you've said this guy is a complete jerk and makes your life miserable and controls everything you do. I have literally no idea why you think it is a difficult decision from what you have said here.

Comment: dilemma in the sense, I thought is is common where ever we go for work. but such type of person is not common in all places. If I quit this job, I have to feed myself till I got the new job, that is the main reason Why I am fearing to quit job.

Comment: @Ganesh, do not agree with these conditions. They are slave labor and abuse. It is more effective to get sleep. It is more effective to work no more than 8 hours continuously. It is more effective to take breaks and to eat all your meals away from your desk rather than working and eating. Your quality of work is impacted when you work too many hours and your quality of work and health are impacted when you skip sleep. Please read this: http://www.alternet.org/story/154518/why_we_have_to_go_back_to_a_40-hour_work_week_to_keep_our_sanity This is a situation where you need to get a new job.

Comment: @Ganesh: I am very sorry for the situation. I see that for trying jobs in other companies also difficult for you as you are also working in the weekends. I strongly suggest you start applying for other companies at least now. Take some vacation in any way (may be as a sick leave) when you get a interview call for preparation. Don't worry about the experience certificate etc. Go out of that hell. All the best.

Comment: Thanks all friends, any way I decided to leave from here today itself and thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Easiest question all day: Quit.

Comment: Thanks all friends, I quit that job and in very small time I got a new job. Thank God.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists some employee rights which all employers need to respect such as asking you to work more than 14 hours a day without paying you an overtime. this is not right. This will lead to several negative impact on your life including your health and social life.

You need to talk to someone superior to him and you need also try to contact an association for the employees right.

In my opinion its useless to continue work for such a company, you are not paid and at the detriment of your health.

Comment: Yes, I agreed with my boss to work more than 14 hours and also liked to work on sundays too but without paying anything is a very difficult even I have to survive. The same thing I told my boss that I have some problems to which I have to take care and so I need salary.but it is of no use. There is one more person who is superior to him, but he wont listen to me what I say anything? And coming to payment, he is not paying to my actual work and I thought for extra work pay is a big miracle. Even If I tell him that I will leave, he may not give me experience certificate. Really my life isin hell

Comment: Ask yourself an honest question. How difficult would be to find another job which at least pays you the same and at least does not involves working more than 40 hours per week?. If you're been underpaid the easiest solution is to switch to an average job.

Comment: Anyone in this situation needs to keep very detailed records. After leaving, send letters of demand for your back pay.  If there is a risk of insolvency, move to wind up the employer, send in debt collectors, or bailiffs if your jurisdiction allows it. If you are working on personal projects for a superior this may be a crime as technically they are embezzling resources.